# Pandas reset_index(drop=True) not working correctly with groupby

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas Datarame as below:

```py
data = {
    'user_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
    'tag_id': [700, 700, 700, 701, 701, 700],
    'score': [1, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 1, 0.6]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

```py
>>> df
   user_id  tag_id  score
0        1     700    1.0
1        1     700    0.9
2        1     700    0.8
3        1     701    0.7
4        1     701    1.0
5        2     700    0.6
```

Then I applied a `groupby` operation on my DataFrame as below, which basically sums scores in a group, **but it doesn't remove indexes**:

```py
df = df.groupby(['user_id', 'tag_id'], as_index=False).sum().reset_index(drop=True)
```

```py
>>> df
   user_id  tag_id  score
0        1     700    2.7
1        1     701    1.7
2        2     700    0.6
```

I also tried removing `as_index` parameter, but it removes other columns, and still the indexes are not removed:

```py
df = df.groupby(['user_id', 'tag_id']).sum().reset_index(drop=True)
```

```py
>>> df
   score
0    2.7
1    1.7
2    0.6
```

Any ideas on **how I can remove these indexes**?

Comment: It is working properly and as expected

Comment: You will always have an index with pandas Dataframe, it's not exactly like a numpy array.

Comment: Thank you for putting a good reproducible pandas example.

Comment: @AnuragDabas Indexes are not removed, I'm using the latest pandas version which is `pandas==1.2.4`

Comment: Pandas will always display index and columns. If no indexes are set, it will use a default index (`pd.RangeIndex`). If you don't want this behaviour then define your own index: `df.set_index('user_id')`

Comment: @Corralien I want to store this DataFrame without indexes with `df.to_sql` command into a database. My main problem is on how can I ignore these indexes

Comment: You can try df.values. This gives you a numpy array of your dataframe without an index

Comment: `df.to_sql(index=False)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67750840/pandas-reset-indexdrop-true-not-working-correctly-with-groupby#comment119753076_67750840) OP expressed his goal

> I want to store this DataFrame without indexes with df.to_sql command
> into a database. My main problem is on how can I ignore these indexes

In order to do that, passing `index=false` in [`pandas.DataFrame.to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) solves the problem

```
df.to_sql(index=False)
```